# How can I use Net::FTP to get a file matching a pattern?

Tags: perl, ftp, design-patterns, match

How can I use [`Net::FTP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aFTP) to get a file matching a pattern?

Basically what I want to do is:

```
$ftp->get("test*");
```

Should match all files starting with test and do a `get()`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [this solution](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=239208) from perlmonks.org.  Essentially do a remote ls, filter out what you don't want with `grep`, then fetch the files.

```
$ftp->get($_) for grep /\.txt$/, $ftp->ls;
```

BTW, this took about 10 seconds to find with [Google "net::FTP mget"](http://www.google.com/search?q=net%3a%3aFTP%20mget&ie=UTF-8)